# Why doesn't the toolbar and search bar show in NavigationStack?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm trying to understand how to add a search bar to a `NavigationStack` using `.searchable` in SwiftUI.
The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/adding-a-search-interface-to-your-app) states:

> Add a search interface to your app by applying one of the searchable view modifiers — like searchable(text:placement:prompt:) — to a NavigationSplitView or NavigationStack, or to a view inside one of these. A search field then appears in the toolbar. The precise placement and appearance of the search field depends on the platform, where you put the modifier in code, and its configuration.

It works in `NavigationSplitView` with this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                Text("Option A")
                Text("Option B")
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("My App Content")
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

The result looks like this
[image: NavigationSplitView with .searchable()]

However it does not work with `NavigationStack` using code like this

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("My App Content")
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

this results in the following appearance

[image: NavigationStack with .searchable()]

Am I doing something wrong?  How can I make the search bar appear with `NavigationStack` in the toolbar the way it does for `NavigationSplitView`?

Comment: I see the searchbar in both cases on iPhone, iPad, and macOS too. What is the version of macOS you are targetting?

Comment: @MatBuompy I can reproduce the issue on macOS 14.1.1 and Xcode 15.0

Comment: Are you building for mac os native (or maybe catalyst) or macOS for designed for iPad?

Comment: Ok, the issue is when building for mac os native. I've replicated it. Now I'm gonna investigate.

Comment: Timmy's answer work. Place the .searchable modifier inside the NavigationStack. It was working either way when bulding for macOS designed for iPad, that's why I could not replicate it.

Comment: thanks, Timmy's answer worked.  Seems like a bug since the docs say it can be applied to `NavigationStack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed the `searchable` modifier inside the `NavigationStack`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("My App Content")
                .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```